# Win store app trial mode

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am confused about the Trial mode of Win 8 Store (metro) apps.

I am reading several resources and documentation like the MSDN site on how to time limit, as that is what I want to do, but the Store provides a trial option on submission on the app - so you can set the Trial mode for 7 days for example.

Is is simply ok to just set this store option of 7 days, and then the app will not open anymore, alerting the user of expiry, or, do i also have to implement time expiry code?

Comment: @Ken White @ Rober Harvey This may be a duplicate question, but I dont think it answers the question though

Comment: I added another answer to the original. See if that helps you.